# Securing Apache Server at port 8080

Tags: apache, security, http, proxy

I have a linux server configured with a major cloud service provider and I had installed a web app on Tomcat Server and also configured Apache as a proxy at port 8080 for my web site. Just yesterday when i logged into my cloud account, i found that the total bandwidth in and out is about 90GB though i had never used this much GB. When I  inquired with the clould support folks they told me the below

> It looks like you have port 8080 open as a http proxy Someone probably found that and has been using that.

What does this mean ? How can someone else use my apache server's port 8080 for their purpose ? How can i prevent this ? I have stopped my server at this point to avoid further misuse.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Deepna

Comment: You might want to check the logs to see _what_ content has been run through your open proxy -- often used for illicit or outright illegal content, such as child pornography. If you're lucky, just spam... Depending upon what you find, it might be useful to report it to law enforcement officials.

Comment: Thanks Sarnold, I have informed the cloud support folks about this and asked them to provide me data from their logs.

Answer (score 2):

You started a *proxy server*. The proxy server works by having people send a request saying, "fetch me page http://example.com", and the proxy goes and fetches it.

Other people then proceeded to use your proxy server to fetch web pages of their choice. Like you were told, it was an open proxy. "open" means unrestricted.

If you are going to make a proxy server on the wide Internet, you must set up proper authentication and authorization. Note the large, visible warning at the top of the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy.html), the proceed to follow the linked directions. You may wish for username/password authentication instead of IP-based. If you do use basic auth, make sure to use SSL in conjunction with it. If you are only using the proxy to access one web page, you could alternately choose not to restrict *who* makes the request, and instead restrict *what* may be requested.

Comment: Thanks Borealid.. Im now trying to get some info on securing my apache. I'm more of a developer, and less of admin, so new to all these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Well from their reply it sounds like someone may be able to browse the web and download files etc through your server.

Basically let's say someone wants to download a 1GB file from any website instead of them downloading it directly they download it via your server, hence increasing your bandwidth usage. Check what's visible on http://www.yoursite.com:8080 ?

"a proxy server is a server (a computer system or an application) that acts as an intermediary for requests from clients seeking resources from other servers. A client connects to the proxy server, requesting some service, such as a file, connection, web page, or other resource available from a different server. "

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: Thanks Leo, I just learnt that the proxy server should be setup as "secured" before enabling proxy requests.